# No access to specific folder for specific user

Tags: server, 22.04, samba

I created the following share via `smb.conf`:

```
 [SEE-Samba Subfolder Username] 
 path = /home/see-admin/SEE-Samba/SEE-Shared/Staff/username
 available = yes
 browseable = yes
 guest ok = no
 write list = username
 valid users = username
 force user = username
```

I also ran:

```
sudo chown -R username: /home/see-admin/SEE-Samba/SEE-Shared/Staff/username
```

The folder shows up in Windows, however, if I open it (logged in with username's credentials), I receive the following error:

```
Windows cannot access \\server.local\SEE-Samba Subfolder Username
You do not have permission to access \\server.local\SEE-Samba Subfolder Username.
Contact your network administrator to request access.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If see-admin is a user name on the server your share will not work since only that user will have access to the entire path to the share.

If you want both "username" on the LAN and "see-admin" on the server to have access to the shared folder I would suggest changing your share definition to this:

```
[SEE-Samba Subfolder Username] 
 path = /home/see-admin/SEE-Samba/SEE-Shared/Staff/username
 available = yes
 browseable = yes
 guest ok = no
 valid users = username
 force user = see-admin
```

"valid users" == will allow only "username" access to the samba share.

"force user" == will make everything he does happen as user see-admin.

And I removed the "write list" operator since you can't have write list and force user together.

Just make sure /home/see-admin/SEE-Samba/SEE-Shared/Staff/username has see-admin as the Linux owner.